# Proving $||A||_1 = \max_{W:\mathcal{H}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_1}(Tr[WA])$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, trace, svd

I've read a couple of times about an alternative way of expressing the trace norm of a complex  matrix $A$, mapping from some finite Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1$ to some other finite Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_2$ (for simplicity, I set $m:=|\mathcal{H}_2|$ and $n:= \mathcal{H}_1$). The alternative expression reads as follows (second equality sign), $||A||_1 := Tr[\sqrt{A^*A}] = \max_{W:\mathcal{H}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_1}(Tr[WA])$, where we take the maximum over all partial isometries from $W$, mapping from $\mathcal{H}_2$ to $\mathcal{H}_1$.

I have never seen any proof of this statement, so I tried to prove it on my own, but I was only partially successful. Here's my attempt:

> Assuming that $m=n$, I was able to show $||A||_1 \leq\max_{W:\mathcal{H}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_1}(Tr[WA])$ by using the
> singular value decomposition of $A$.
>
> For $A$ the singular value decomposition reads $A = U \Sigma V^*$,
> where $U$ and $W$ are unitaries. Then we find that $\sqrt{A^*A} = \sqrt{(U\Sigma V)^*(U\Sigma V)} = \sqrt{V \Sigma^{\top}\Sigma V^*} = V\Sigma V^*$.
>
> Hence, we deduce $||A||_1 = Tr[\sqrt{A^*A}] = Tr[V \Sigma V^*] = Tr[VU^*U\Sigma V^*] = Tr[W A] \leq \max_{W:\mathcal{H}_2 \rightarrow
> > \mathcal{H}_1}(Tr[WA])$
> , where we set $W := VU^*$.

Unfortunately, I have serious problems when I try to prove the general case, where $m \neq n$, similiarly, as, for example, $\sqrt{V \Sigma^{\top}\Sigma V^*} = V \Sigma V^*$ doesn't make sense any more because the dimensions don't fit. The same applies to several equalities the second line of argumentation.

I wondered if I just can "extend" the dimensions of the matrices such that the matrix multiplications are defined by adding zeros (so "enforcing" square matrices), but I am not sure whether this changes the singular value decomposition. Furthermore, the statement asks explicitly for partial isometries from $\mathcal{H}_2$ to $\mathcal{H}_1$, so I would manipulate the statement.

Does anyone have an idea how I can prove this statement (so this direction, and/or the reverse one, where I haven't found a promising approach)?

Comment: what you are calling a 'trace norm' is also known as a nuclear norm or Schatten 1 norm, commonly denoted by $\big\Vert A\big \Vert_{S_1}$.  Applying the von Neumann trace inequality should give you the upper bound in general; and by wise choice of $W$ you can show this is met with equality.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your helpful comment! I managed to find the upper bound on the maximum by using von Neumann's ineuality (haven't heard of this before, so it was a bit of work to clarify the details, but I guess it is easy once you've seen this once before). Unfortunately, I do not see how  this choice of $W$ should look like. Do you have some hint what you had in mind?

Comment: There's different ways to finish.  If you want to work directly with the case $m\neq n$: Suppose $A$ is tall and skinny (if not, work with $A^*$) then $A=U\Sigma V^*$ with $\Sigma$ and $V$ square, but $U$ is tall and skinny -- SVD is not unique in many ways so you many choose the factorization to fit your needs.  Finally $W:= VU^*$. Note that $WW^* = I$  so all singular values are 1.

Comment: btw since we are working over complex scalars, $\max_{W:\mathcal{H}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_1}(Tr[WA])$ may technically be problematic.  Better to write this as $\max_{W:\mathcal{H}_2 \rightarrow  \mathcal{H}_1}\big \vert Tr[WA] \big \vert$